# How can I convert string into a table format

Tags: php, string

I have a string

```
    Part Number | Hose Size / MM ID | Hose Size / MM OD | WORKING PRESSURE / PSI MAX | WORKING PRESSURE / PSI Min Burst | MIN BEND RADIUS / MM | WEIGHT PER METRE / KG | HOSE COUPLING
    1MH-03 | 3/16" | 11.9 | 3630 | 14520 | 89 | 0.18 | TP / FA
```

How can I convert string into a table format. '|' means next column

Comment: explode by newline, each exploded line, explode it again by pipe

Comment: i didn't get your point fully can you please let me know via code.. it will be great help.. thanks in advance

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: echo table tag then explode the main string and loop each result with foreach along with tr tag, then each row explode, each piece foreach again, echo along with td. that's it. there's no harm in trying

Comment: I assume the first line of your string would be the table header? Then the second line would be the table data? Also, is this all in one string or two strings?

Comment: Define your strings as two separate variables, then explode them at the `|`. Count the results of one of the arrays. Then combine the two arrays `combine_array()` within a for loop using the count as your ticker. Then build your table using two foreach loops looping over the combined arrays key/value pairs. Your key will be your `<th>` and your value will be your `<td>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<?php
$string = "....."; //your string
$lines = explode("\n",$string); //store the string to array line by line
foreach($lines as $line){
   $cols = explode("|",$line); //spliting each line by pipe
    echo "<tr>";
   foreach($cols as $col){
       echo "<td>".$col."</td>";
   }
   echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Doesn't work if columns data contain "|"

Comment: i made some changes & it worked